# Why is getAccuracyBearingDegrees() returning 0.0 while trying to getBearing()?

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, android-location, bearing

I am working on a compass app that gets the bearing (direction of travel) using Android's Location classes getBearing() function. I want to filter the location's bearing values using the getAccuracyBearingDegrees() function (to account for spikes in GPS, inaccurate signals etc). Now I can technically also use location.getAccuracy() function too since location is used to get bearing anyway, yet the getAccuracyBearingDegrees() looks more reasonable to use in this scenario. However it is always returning 0.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Thanks in advance...